# Does より mean から in the following context?

Tags: particles, particle-より

I came across the following sentence

> 春秋社**より**楽譜出版。

I think it means “music scores published by 春秋社. But what usage of より is this? Does it mean から (from) here

Comment: ahh... it depends on the context. Do you have the surrounding text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That's exactly what it means.

より can have several uses depending on context, including "from", "rather", "since", "than", etc. You'll learn to distinguish between these uses given time and reading practice.